# Query about details of image as webParts

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

According to the article on Microsoft Docs webParts contains various other fields like title,description,dataVersion,properties(startDate,endDate,webId etc.) and much more.

Following is the link:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#feedback

But when I'm trying to do the same, in my webParts for images only type and instanceId field is showing.
Please tell me that how to further retrieve the data(details about image webPart) from that instanceId.

I have typed the following query on Microsoft Graph Explorer:-

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/dextorlab.sharepoint.com,32f65d1c-0ac4-472c-bc01-c9e7b16e5463,0ca66773-81b0-4d23-80c4-6e7dad22df53/pages/496ed374-65ea-4ca6-8c3b-f78f4e90911b/webParts

The text part of the webParts is showing under the tag "rte" , everything is fine about that.
But for some other webParts like images, instanceId is given and type and id is given in some fixed pattern.
I want to know that how the details of the webParts like images can be retrieved further.

[Expected Output about image webPart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLp1G.png)

[Getting following response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj3H6.png)

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish. You are talking about docs, it's useful to include links to the pages you've found.

Comment: Sir I've mentioned the link and outputs also in this edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887357/how-fetch-webparts-from-site-pages